# Generating labels from a log line using promtail and send it to grafana loki

Tags: grafana-loki, promtail

I want to ship logs from promtail to loki and visualize in grafana. But i am not able to parse them in promtail, meaning the labels are not getting generated

```
server:
  http_listen_port: 9080
  grpc_listen_port: 0

positions:
  filename: /tmp/positions.yaml

clients:
  - url: 'http://loki_ip:3100/loki/api/v1/push'
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: apache-logs
    static_configs:
      - targets:
          - localhost
        labels:
          job: apache-logs
          __path__: /opt/httpd-2.4.57/logs/3dx_access.log
          host: 3dx
      - targets:
          - localhost
        labels:
          job: test
          __path__: /opt/httpd-2.4.57/logs/sample.log
          host: test

    pipeline_stages:
      - regex:
          expression: '\\[(.*?)\\] \\| (\\d+) \\| (\\d+) ms \\| (\\d+) B \\| (.*?) \\| - \\| - \\| - \\| \"(.*?)\"'
          labels:
            timestamp: "${1}"
            status_code: "${2}"
            duration_ms: "${3}"
            bytes: "${4}"
            ip: "${5}"
            method: "${6}"
            url: "${7}"
```

Here is the sample log line which i want to parse

```
[14/Sep/2023:17:17:56 +0530] | 404 | 0 ms | 807 B | 172.31.0.88 | - | - | - | "GET /3dcomment/monitoring/healthcheck HTTP/1.1"
```

After i save this config and restart promtail in grafana loki i am just seeing three labels job, host and filename. Why am i not able to send the labels created from the regex?

Answer (score 0):

I have only ever used named groups in my regex. So...

```
      expression: '\\[(.*?)\\] \\| (\\d+) \\| (\\d+) ms \\| (\\d+) B \\| (.*?) \\| - \\| - \\| - \\| \"(.*?)\"'
      labels:
        timestamp: "${1}"
        status_code: "${2}"
```

becomes (partial example only and regex not validated)...

```
      expression: '\\[(?<ts>.*?)\\] \\| (?P<sc>\\d+)...
      labels:
        timestamp: ts
        status_code: sc
```

However, you do not want the timestamp as a label as Loki will save it automatically and each label increases cardinality (bad thing). Additionally, you might want to use the timestamp stage to replace the incoming time with the log line time.

You might even want to use a JSON stage instead of labels then in the query in Grafana unwrap it. This is often faster than labels.